# Download file from specific server folder using Node JS

Tags: node.js, file

I'm implementing a rest API to download files from specific source into a server, I'm using routing-controllers, but I generate an error, for testing purposes I'm harcoding the locally path of the file that I need to download in the browser.

```
@Get('/download')
  downloadFile(@Res() response: Response) {    
    response.download(`C:/Attachments/Folder_1/test.pdf`);
}
```

Error:

```
Error
at NotFoundError.HttpError [as constructor] (C:\PERSONAL\EA\SAI\SAI-API\sai-api\node_modules\routing-controllers\http-error\HttpError.js:27:23)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the slashes in your hard-coded path shouldn't be backslashes?

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk I tried, but same error

Comment: i suggest you to use path module,If you are not using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was solved using this implementation:

```
@Get('/download')
async downloadDocument(@Res() response: Response) {    
  await promisify<string, void>(response.download.bind(response))(`C:/Attachments/Folder_1/test.pdf`)
  return response;    
}
```

Comment: To get a more elaborate discussion of this issue, checkout [this link](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers/issues/288).